# jQuery UI checkbox button showing normal checkbox

Tags: jquery-ui, checkbox

HTML:

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<label for="1">Online</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').button();
});
```

When rendered in the browser it is showing both a traditional checkbox and a button underneath. I can click on either one and they will toggle the checkbox. This is the HTML in the browser:

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<label for="1" class="ui-state-active ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Online</span></label>
```

When I enter the same into jsfiddle it works perfectly, get just the toggle button. So I'm at a loss what is causing this?

Comment: Not quite sure if this is it, but maybe you want `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is wrong. You need to add " to the type, like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').button();
```

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't make a difference. Also, it looks to me like the button part is working since the elements have all those ui-* class attributes.

Comment: Did you add the jquery-ui.css and made sure the images are being referenced correctly?